# Spring MVC 3 redirect / forward with sitemesh

Tags: java, spring-mvc, sitemesh

Greetings all,

I am using spring mvc 3 + sitemesh and spring security 3. i need to do the following scenario.
i am using 2 different layouts for the bypassing users and normal users. the approach i followed was working fine until i came across with some JavaScript popups because i noticed that the page was loading twice and poping up the same window twice. please validate my approach.

Controller class-

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/mainMenu")
    public class PortalController {

     @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String byPassPortal() {

    if (User.bypassMenu()) {
         //return "redirect:user.html";
         //return "forward:user.html";
         return "/user/user";
    } else {
        // send user to the portal page
        logger.debug("Redirect to the main page");
        return "mainMenu";
    }
    }
}
```

site mesh decorator xml -

```
<decorators defaultdir="/decorators">
<decorator name="layout" page="layout.jsp">
    <pattern>/user*</pattern>
</decorator>
<decorator name="default" page="default.jsp">
    <pattern>/*</pattern>
</decorator>
</decorators>
```

here are my observations - if i use `return "redirect:user.html";` & `return "forward:user.html";`  it was working fine with the correct layout (`layout.jsp`) for users since decorator will catch it by pattern `<pattern>/user*</pattern>`. but the problem is form will load twice and i get the popup twice.

if i use `return "forward:user.html";` or `return "/user/user";` popup will come only once but the layout is wrong.cause should be that it will not captured from the decorator for url pattern `<pattern>/user*</pattern>` and it will use the default layout which is wrong (`default.jsp`).

I think there is something to handle from the spring side and not from the sitemesh. can you please give some guidance among this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi all, i found the issue.there was nothing to do with spring or sitemesh. it was all about the second layout that i was using. it contained two '<decorator:head />' tags and it submitted twice by the sitemesh. Hope this will help for anyone who got this kind of error down the line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the issue.there was nothing to do with spring or sitemesh. it was all about the second layout that i was using. it contained two '' tags and it submitted twice by the sitemesh. Hope this will help for anyone who got this kind of error down the line. – Sam 0 secs ago edit